# Laravel Production issue - Updating composer with Laravel 4.1.x

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I haven't encountered any issue in deploying my laravel project until now. I've been deploying for like almost a year already for this project. But some new bug came up.

First of all. 
I can't run composer update, cause it says this error.

```
composer update
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)



  [RuntimeException]
  Could not load package classpreloader/classpreloader in http://packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint ^1.2.2: Invalid
   version string "^1.2.2"






  [UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse version constraint ^1.2.2: Invalid version string "^1.2.2"



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

So what I did is update my Composer library.

This is my current version.

```
 Composer version 1e27ff5e22df81e3cd0cd36e5fdd4a3c5a031f4a 2014-08-11 15:46:48
```

I updated composer.

```
[api@my staging-hoho-middleware]$ sudo composer self-update^C
[api@my staging-hoho-middleware]$ sudo /usr/local/bin/composer self-update
Updating to version b2173d28fc8b56236eddc8aa10dcda61471633ec.
    Downloading: 100%
Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 1e27ff5e22df81e3cd0cd36e5fdd4a3c5a031f4a
[api@my staging-hoho-middleware]$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

But I encounter a new problem once I ran composer update

```
[api@my staging-hoho-middleware]$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.7.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.7.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.7.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.7.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.4.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.4.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.4.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.4.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.4.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.4.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.3.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.3.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.3.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.3.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.3.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.3.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.2.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.2.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

     - phpunit/phpunit 4.0.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.                                                                                     [0/1888]
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.0.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.0.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.38 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.37 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.36 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.35 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.34 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.33 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.32 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.31 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.30 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.29 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.28 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.27 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.26 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.25 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.24 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.23 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.22 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.21 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.20 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.19 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.18 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.17 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.16 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.15 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.14 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.13 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit * -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.10, 3.7.11, 3.7.12, 3.7.13, 3.7.14, 3.7.15, 3.7.16, 3.7.17, 3.7.18, 3.7.19, 3.7.2, 3.7.20, 3.7.21, 3.7.
22, 3.7.23, 3.7.24, 3.7.25, 3.7.26, 3.7.27, 3.7.28, 3.7.29, 3.7.3, 3.7.30, 3.7.31, 3.7.32, 3.7.33, 3.7.34, 3.7.35, 3.7.36, 3.7.37, 3.7.38, 3.7.4, 3.7.5, 3.7.6, 3.7.7, 3.7.8, 3.7.9, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.10, 4
.0.11, 4.0.12, 4.0.13, 4.0.14, 4.0.15, 4.0.16, 4.0.17, 4.0.18, 4.0.19, 4.0.2, 4.0.20, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2,
 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.2.5, 4.2.6, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.3.2, 4.3.3, 4.3.4, 4.3.5, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.2, 4.4.3, 4.4.4, 4.4.5, 4.5.0, 4.5.1, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.6.10, 4.6.2, 4.6.3, 4.6.4, 4.6.5, 4.6.6, 4.6.7, 4.6.8, 4.6.9,
 4.7.0, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.7.3].
```

Now I am leaning towards uninstalling my composer, and creating a new fresh copy.

Comment: It's frustrating that that the php extension dom that's missing isn't included in the error message.  Installing php-xml fixed it for me.  How did you know that's what was missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed it by installing the missing dependencies.

```
1008  php -v
1009  yum search php55
1010  yum -y install php55w-xml.x86_64 
1011  clear
1012  su - api
1013  httpd restart
1014  service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 54):

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

fixed this for me on Ubuntu with PHP 5.6. (Its nothing to do with Laravel BTW - I'm not using that framework at all.)

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-xml worked for me. It was pointed out by Peter Wiseman in the earlier answer(I have php7)

Comment: php 7 can use `sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml`

Comment: @JsLim Correct, firstly I tried with `sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml` but for some reason your line only worked for me.

Comment: @Tpojka if you're using 7.1, I assume you already add in the php repo to apt list. just run `sudo apt-get update` then install the 7.1 xml

Comment: @JsLim mistake by myself. It is **7.0.10** version out there NOT *7.1*.

Comment: true that, this problem is dependency issue with PHP

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem, performed the composer installation command in the terminal and problem solved

the composer via yum install command:

```
yum install composer -y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install phpunit, after that, if there are problems, execute the command: `sudo a2dismod php5` .If you still have questions, to analyze your problem by looking at the system log.