# Laravel Composer update failed Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-4, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04

I ran composer update in my project that I cloned because I changed my computer. And it's returned the following errors, but I don't get how to solved them... :

> Problem 1
>       - The requested PHP extension ext-mcrypt * is missing from your 
>   system. Install or enable PHP's mcrypt extension.
>
> Problem 2
>       - Installation request for guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.3].
>       - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
>
> Problem 3
>       - Installation request for phpoffice/phpexcel 1.8.1 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpexcel[1.8.1].
>       - phpoffice/phpexcel 1.8.1 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.
>
> Problem 4
>       - Installation request for sentry/sentry 1.5.0 -> satisfiable by sentry/sentry[1.5.0].
>       - sentry/sentry 1.5.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
>
> Problem 5
>       - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
>       - intercom/intercom-php v1.0.0 requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.9 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.3].
>       - Installation request for intercom/intercom-php v1.0.0 -> satisfiable by intercom/intercom-php[v1.0.0].

Comment: 1) http://serverfault.com/questions/488678/the-requested-php-extension-ext-mcrypt-is-missing-from-your-system, 2 & 4 & 5) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335305/composer-install-error-requires-ext-curl-when-its-actualy-enabled, 3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868608/laravel-production-issue-updating-composer-with-laravel-4-1-x

Comment: I already tried the 1, after hitting sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt returned me : "E: Package 'php5-mcrypt' has no installation candidate"

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: I finally got it ! I had to right php5.6 instead if php5 for each command line... Sorry for the post it was pointless...

Comment: Is this a PHP 5 or 7 project ? If it's a php5, you will have to follow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36789471/2702147, if it's a php7 project: `sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The final solution was to run this :

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

For Php -V 7

> ```
> sudo apt-get install php7.1-mcrypt
> sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl
> sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just install missed extensions, as Composer reported.

```
sudo apt-get install php-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php-curl
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Php -V 8**

sudo apt-get install php8.1-mcrypt

sudo apt-get install php8.1-curl

sudo apt-get install php8.1-xml